# Having LTRFootnote in the caption of figure

Tags: captions

How can I have `LTRfootnote` in the caption of figure?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make a minimal compilable example and post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption[Test]{Test\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\LTRfootnotetext{some footnote text}

Here is some text\LTRfootnote{a test footnote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is created in previous page. What shall I do?

Comment: @user148494 I tried to recreate the problem you described, but I was not able to. Please provide a complete MWE that replicates the issue.